# How to reload a module once I’ve deleted or modified its functions?

Tags: module, dolphindb

I made some changes to the definition of a module function. Later when I called this function, it still ran the old way. How can I actually replace the previous function definition and make my changes effective?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Dolphindb GUI? After syncing modules to server, you need restart the session to load the latest modules. The simplest way: choose another server in the toolbar and then change back, you will get your latest modules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the command clearCachedModules() after updating the module. Then when you import the module with the use statement again, the system reloads it from the module file instead of using the cached data, and there is no need to restart the node. Note that only an administrator can execute clearCachedModules().